# Pickling (or otherwise saving) 15GB of RandomForestClassifier objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pickle

I am working with `sklearn` and training a couple hundred `RandomForestClassifier`s for my project. The final result consists of a list of the classifiers, which take about 15GB of RAM memory (my machine has 32GB RAM in total). In order to be able to retrieve the classifiers at a later point in time, I tried to `pickle` them:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump( classifierList, open( ".\saved\saveAll.p", "wb" ) )
```

However, after a few minutes I get the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:_env\project\series\save.py", line 11, in
>
> pickle.dump( classifierList, open( ".\saved\saveAll.p", "wb" ) )
>
> MemoryError

and the python script crashes without writing anything to `saveAll.p`.

Is it possible to save this list of classifiers successfully? Am I doing something wrong in the pickle syntax? Perhaps there are other, better ways to save these objects, to efficiently load them later, apart from pickling?
Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: If you have at least Python v3.8 and numpy v1.16 you could try [Pickle protocol 5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0574/) with [`pickle.dump( classifierList, open(".\saved\saveAll.p", "wb"), protocol=5)`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html).

Comment: @rickhg12hs thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I'm on python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the [`sklearn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) documentation, the `joblib` module is more efficient than the `pickle` module.